# Can't see plugin in target platform to set as Eclipse plugin dependency

Tags: eclipse, dependencies, eclipse-plugin, target-platform

My understanding is that the set of plugins that one can choose from, in setting the dependencies of a plugin, is determined by the active target platform.

I've created a target platform and set it as the active target in Preferences.  I can see the  plugin I want to depend on in its "Content" pane in Eclipse.  But when I try to add the plugin as a "Required Plug-in" in the Dependencies pane of my depending plugin project, it's not on the list to select from.  If I add it using the raw manifest text editor, Eclipse complains that it can't find the depended-on plugin in the "Problems" pane.

I'm a newbie at this, so if an "Is it plugged in?" (so to speak) possibility comes to mind, it certainly is a possibility.

I'm not using p2, maven, etc... I just added a directory to the target platform definition.

Comment: Check that the check box next to the plug-in is checked in the Content pane of the Target Platform. And the target platform is checked (and says Active) on the main Target Platform list.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks much, but been there, done that, sadly.

Comment: Also try the `Reload...` button on the main Target Platform page.

Comment: For what it's worth, I was seeing different versions of a recently upgraded plugin in my dev environment and target platform, even though the configuration settings agreed.  Eventually, restarting the dev environment process seemed to refresh the target platform's plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is that setting the target platform via the Preferences page doesn't do what's necessary to the projects so that they can see the plugins in the new target platform.  Instead, one must open the target platform and click on the "Set as Target Platform" link in the upper right corner of the editor.

This is based on limited experience, and thus may be a superstition.